# menu items outside of blog

Tags: menus

Is there way that I can echo out my wordpress menu items to a main site menu.
The wordpress install runs in a subfolder of my main site.

I thought there might be a way to do this that is similar to referencing wp-load as a include outside of wordpress

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52629/73)? You can fetch and embed the result without an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referring to something like this:

```
<?php 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( '/absolute/path/to/wp-blog-header.php' );
wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

but the current menu item highlighting will not work as expected.